# toUppercase () en java

Tags: java, usecase

[image: Necesito realizar un programa que el usuario dijite una palabra, y mediante del SWICTH]

Necesito realizar un programa que el usuario dijite una palabra, y mediante del SWICTH el usuario elije que opcion desea realizar: como mostrar el primer carácter, mostrar el ultimo carácter y también mostrar la palabra en mayúscula.

Comment: Ese código debe ir en la pregunta, no en el área de comentarios. Por favor, haz clic en [edit] para que agregues eso a tu pregunta. Explica lo que hace ese código, el error o problema que tienes con el mismo y el resultado esperado. Puedes leer [ask] y [mcve]. Saludos

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: En vez de borrar las preguntas, pulsa en "editar" y modifícala ahí, incluyendo el código.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so] te invito a [edit] tu pregunta agregando el codigo que dejastes en el comentario, y tambien a hacer el [tour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No entiendo muy bien dónde encuentras el problema. El caso es que el ejercicio de por si te da todas las pautas y pistas que necesitas para solventarlo. En breves palabras, el resultado de tu programa base (digo base,porque ya está en ti cambiar/ampliar cualquier parte) seria:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Stk {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        String palabra;
        System.out.println("Dime la palabra");
        palabra=entrada.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Elige la opcion, 1-...... 2-..... 3-.....");
        switch(entrada.nextLine()) {
            case "1":
                System.out.println("Primera letra: " + palabra.charAt(0));
                break;
            case "2":
                System.out.println("Ultima letra: " + palabra.charAt(palabra.length()-1));
                break;
            case "3":
                System.out.println("Mayusculas: " + palabra.toUpperCase());
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Y ya está, no tiene más. A esto le puedes poner un caracter de salida si quieres y crear un cuarto caso, dejando el default para "error de entrada" (todo esto dentro de un bucle, pej: while (salida!=true), haciendo en el case 4 (el de la salida) salida==true;)

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]

Comment: @gbianchi Lo sé! me olvide de poner que no me dejaba comentar y por eso lo ponía aquí. Pido perdón por ello, aunque el caso es que como en el hilo no se incluye código, no sabía si estaba bien darle el código funcional (a parte de que no queda claro dónde tiene el problema específicamente). Como moderador, te pregunto, debería darle el código completo? (me pongo a ello si así lo indicas). Gracias

Comment: Fijate que en los comentarios dejo un poco de su codigo, pero su pregunta sigue sin ser clara de donde esta el problema...

Comment: y no.. en los ejercicios tratamos de no resoverlos...

Comment: Debería pues, proceder a borrar mi respuesta? (mientras tanto, he editado mi respuesta, para cumplir mi parte con las normas, perdón nuevamente).

Comment: bueno.. fijate que asi, le resolviste directamente el ejercicio... vos podes hacer lo que quieras.. pero pensa que bien te hubiera hecho si en lugar de pensar los ejercicios por vos mismo, te hubieran dado la solucion...

Comment: Gracias de todas maneras, y si lo tenia ya un poco resuelto pero no entendí la manera de acomodarlo.